# delete or update operations is not working on hive 0.14

Tags: hadoop, hive, operations

Anyone knows why the delete/update operation is not working in hive 0.14 (it's supposed to be working starting 0.14 version) even I do follow the steps/format to create table and get:

> FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10294]: Attempt to do update or delete using transaction manager that does not support these operations.

upon running delete operation. Please help me on this.

```
CREATE TABLE STUDENT
(
STD_ID INT,
STD_NAME STRING,
AGE INT,
ADDRESS STRING
)
CLUSTERED BY (ADDRESS) into 3 buckets
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
STORED as orc tblproperties('transactional'='true');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete and update works from 0.14 onwards. I was able to achieve the same.
You need to set new configuration parameters in Hive

```
 hive.support.concurrency – true
 hive.enforce.bucketing – true
 hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode – nonstrict
 hive.txn.manager –org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.lockmgr.DbTxnManager
 hive.compactor.initiator.on – true
 hive.compactor.worker.threads – 1
```

Then create a table with ACID support,

```
     CREATE TABLE STUDENT
(
STD_ID INT,
STD_NAME STRING,
AGE INT,
ADDRESS STRING
)
CLUSTERED BY (ADDRESS) into 3 buckets
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
STORED as orc tblproperties('transactional'='true');
```

and do CURD opertaions.

```
update STUDENT 
    set AGE = 24 
    where STD_ID = 19;
```

Please follow these [steps](http://unmeshasreeveni.blogspot.in/2014/11/updatedeleteinsert-in-hive-0140.html)

Comment: I can't add hive.txn.manager property as it is not stable and with all those flags I am still getting the same error

Comment: @rawal:  great.If the answer is helpfull please accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

1.Set the properties below in hive-site.xml

2.Create the table newly again

3.Load the data in to table

4.Try for CRUD operations. It will work. Good luck

```
<property>
  <name>hive.support.concurrency</name>
  <value>true</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>hive.enforce.bucketing</name>
  <value>true</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode</name>
  <value>nonstrict</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>hive.txn.manager</name>
  <value>org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.lockmgr.DbTxnManager</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>hive.compactor.initiator.on</name>
  <value>true</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>hive.compactor.worker.threads</name>
  <value>1</value>
</property>
```

Comment: I can't add hive.txn.manager property as it is not stable and with all required flags I am still getting the same error